# OpenCV.VideoWriter crops somehow video, accidentally

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, video-processing

This is not your typical question about how to crop a video. It is precisely the opposite. OpenCV is cutting my frames, I don't know how.

I have the following code:

```
    test_X.shape
```

Output:

```
(1803,302,154,3)
```

Now, the main code:

```
prediction = np.argmax(test_Y_predicted,axis=1)

video_out = cv2.VideoWriter('Video_con_clasificación.avi',
                            cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'),
                            10, (154,302))
for i in range(len(test_Y)):
    if test_Y[i] != prediction[i]:
        # Frames were normalized, so...
        image = (test_X[i]*255).astype(np.uint16)
        video_out.write(cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
        cv2.imshow(title,image.astype(np.uint8))
        cv2.waitKey(500)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video_out.release()
```

Here is an image provided by that `cv2.imshow`:

[image: imshow image]

And this is the video which I can create :(

[image: videoWriter]

Surely I have a problem with the channels, it's not the same color.... But I'm worried about the picture seen in video. It is a cropped version of that provided by `imshow`.

Do you fight with any similar issue?

Comment: Not just cropped, it looks like the image is stretched to twice the width and then cropped to the original width. That leads me to think that it's likely the fact you're feeding array of  `np.uint16` to the `VideoWriter` instance, and it's not entirely happy about it.

Comment: That's it. I don't know why openCV told me that I must use uint16 (because it appears in an error early). Converting np.array (float32) to uint8 works fine. Other problem is related with the channels, but... Thank you

Do you know how I can close the question?